# Is there a way to read the crash log of an app at runtime

Tags: ios, crash-reports

Is there a way to read the crash log of an app at runtime?

What I mean is this, have some method running at the first beginning of an app that will monitor if the app crashed last time. If so, it will read the crash log, attach it to an email and send it to me.

I know apple has that functionality on iTC but it just shows crashes for a large amount of users and I want to know about all crashes that may be happening without my knowledge. You know, users don't give a crap and will never warn you.

Is this possible?

Comment: how are you going to send an email to yourself without user's knowledge? For the privacy reason alone your app may get rejected and may get you booted out from appstore.

Comment: Read apple review guidelines 2.1 and 2.2 for iOS

Comment: I use https://www.plcrashreporter.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the TestFlight SDK. If the app crashes a crash report can be read on the website.

https://testflightapp.com/sdk